# How do I find the error of a curve rather than points.

Tags: statistics, curves, linear-regression, programming

In school, I've learned numerous ways to compare sets of points to see how well the collection of data fits a curve, such as linear regression, and ways to compare sets of data to see how well they fit each other with methods like Chi-Squared. What is the most acceptable way to do the same for two curves? For example, in the picture I have attached, I am comparing blue (y=sin(2pi*x)) and green (y=sin(pi*x)-0.1) curves to black (y=sin(pi*x)) to see which is a better fit. If I were to sample every integer x value for the blue and black curves and compare them, I would find a perfect match, when in reality, the green curve matches much closer to the black curve for most other sampling resolutions. I understand this might be an edge case, but what is a reliable way to decide how close a curve matches another curve?
[Curves Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rba2q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of least squares, or linear regression, is to minimize the $l^2$ (discrete case) or $L^2$ (continuous case) norm of the data.  So, a measure of how well curve $f(x)$ approximates curve $g(x)$ is given by
$$\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx =: ||f-g||^2_{[a,b]}.$$
This measures the error on the interval $[a,b]$.
So, the curve $f(x)$ which better approximates $g(x)$ would be the curve with the smaller norm.

Comment: This was my first thought, but it seemed computationally inefficient. I think this is what I will try to use though. Thank you.

Comment: Ok.  But it should not be very intensive.  If you are working with smooth functions, integration can be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

[Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) (for non-negative functions):

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \log \left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)\ dx$$

As far as I know, there is no corresponding function for general continuous functions (that could be negative).  The generalization of the sum-squared-error, though, would be proportional to:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x) - g(x))^2\ dx$$

normalized.

Comment: The OP asks about curves which are not probability distributions; they are negative for some values of $x$.  Does this still apply?